# added custom rewrite rule to wordpress and it does not work at all

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

```
function rewrite_support() {
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule('^support/category/([^/]+)/?$','support-category/?category=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_support');
```

Is there a reason why this is not working? I've included this code in my functions.php file.

/support-category/?category=category name

should redirect to:

/support/category/category name

This does not appear to be working:

Comment: Try to escape the `?`with a \ . it's a regexp special character.

Comment: that managed to break my page but did not rewrite the url...

Comment: What was the exact error message then?

Comment: No error message my page just went blank. i think it has something to do with the flush. Either way though there was no redirect happening. This seems like it should be quite easy to do...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^support-category/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?pagename=support/category&category_name=$matches[1]','top');
```

or

```
add_rewrite_rule('^support/category/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?pagename=support-category&category_name=$matches[1]','top');
```